# Search for 2 values that must be exist in a row and then return a value from different column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have values in column A, B, and C:

1 - 1 - 2

1 - 2 - 3

2 - 2 - 4

3 - 4 - 1

2 - 3 - 5

and another column (let assume this is in column E):

1

1

2

3

4

Note: all columns start at row 1.

I want to search for the row that contains the value of E1 in the range of column A and the value of E2 in the range of column B. If the row contains both values return the value in column C

I have created the following function in column F:

=IF(AND(E1=$A$1:$A$4,E2=$B$1:$B$4),$C$1:$C$4)

it works only if the values that match my criteria are in the same row otherwise I got false. Example to elaborate the problem:

E     F                         A   B    C

1     2  ---------------------> 1   1    2 : Because E1 = A1 and E2 = B1 - F1 will be = 2

1     3  ---------------------> 1   2    3 : because E2 = A2 and E3 = B2 - F2 will be = 3
2     false  -----------------> 2   2    4 : because E3 = A3 but E4 != B3 - F3 is false (it should be 5)

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm very confused by your question. It sounds like you want it to give the value of Cx where x is the row where Ax and Bx = E1 and E2 respectively, but then you say you want it to work if it finds E2 in any row of B. Do you want it to check for a specific row with these values or do you want it to just check if they are in A and B at all? If so, which row of C do you wanted returned? The A row, or the B row?

Comment: Also, are you trying to compare each E row to it's respective A and B rows? I.E., E1 & E2 - A1 & B1, E2 & E3 - A2 & B2, E3 &E4 - A3 & B3, or are you trying to compare each E row to each A and B row? Or each E row to each A and B row beginning at the E row? I would really need a much clearer explanation of what you want to help. Explaining what the point of this function is (what your ultimate goal is and why) might help clear it up as well.

Comment: @Layne The idea is to search for the row that contains the value of Ex and E(x+1) and then return the corresponding value of C (from the same row). Say E1=2 and E2=3. The goal is to search all rows until finding row (r) that contains both values where E1=Ar and E2=Br and then return the value of Cr. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Example of the idea: https://imgur.com/a/ryfgDv9 I do that because I have dependencies between the cells of the column. Each cell in the column linked with the following cell (as shown in column E). Also, I have another table contains the reasons for all these dependencies. Therefore, I am looking for a function that returns the reason for the dependency between all cells in the sub-list (E) instead of jumping between tables every single minute.

Comment: I gotcha, what was tripping me up is I wasn't sure if you meant a single row as in `(Ax,Bx) = (E1,E2)` or multiple rows as in `(Ax,By) = (E1,E2)`. When you said "it works only if the values that match my criteria are in the same row otherwise I got false"  I thought you might mean multiple rows and then I was confused about which row (x or y) that you wanted back. Now I realize you meant they only matched when the criteria matched on the same row as the first E column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

`=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1,(E1=A:A)*(E2=B:B),0))`

Unfortunately I can't take credit for this, as it comes from [this excellent article on exceljet.net](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria)

The (most) relevant part, with some typo corrections:

> **How this formula works:**
>
> Normally, an INDEX MATCH formula is configured
>   with MATCH set to look through a one-column range and provide a match
>   based on a given criteria. Without concatenating values in a helper
>   column, or in the formula itself, there's no way to supply more than
>   one criteria.
>
> This formula works around this limitation by using boolean logic to
>   create an array of ones and zeros to represent rows matching all 3
>   criteria, then using MATCH to match the first 1 found.
>
> The temporary array of ones and zeros is based on this snippet:
>
> `(H5=B5:B11)*(H6=C5:C11)*(H7=D5:D11)`
>
> Here we compare the item H5 against all items, the size in H6 against all sizes, and the color in
>   H7 against all colors. The initial result looks like this:
>
> `{TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE}*{FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE}*{TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE}`
>
> The multiplication operation transforms the TRUE FALSE values to 1s
>   and 0s:
>
> `{1;1;1;0;0;0;1}*{0;0;1;0;0;1;0}*{1;0;1;0;0;0;1}`
>
> And the final result
>   looks like this:
>
> `{0;0;1;0;0;0;0}`
>
> Which goes into MATCH as the lookup array:
>
> `MATCH(1,{0;0;1;0;0;0;0})`
>
> MATCH returns 3, and the entire formula boils
>   down to a standard INDEX MATCH formula
>
> `=INDEX(E5:E11,3)`
>
> with a final result of $17.00.

Comment: perfect. It works!. Just a quick mention to anyone has the same prob to press ctrl+shift+enter with this formula.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this Array formula:**

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$5,SMALL(IF(($A$1:$A$5=E1)*($B$1:$B$5=E2),ROW($1:$5)-ROW($1:$1)),ROW($A1))),"")}
```

**N.B.**

- Finish the Formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.
- Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.